# Transforming SQL process into SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have a sql query that has more than 200 lines of codes with the following steps. I need to run this everyday and generate Table A. I have a new requirement to make a SSIS package with the same process and create the tableA with ssis . The below details are the current SQL process

1. drop  table_A
2. select into table_A from (select tableB union all select tableC union all TableD)
   key fators : table_B, table_C, table_D - I need to pull 20 columns out of 40 columns from these three tables. The columns names vary and I need to 
   rename and standardisse the column names and certain data type so that it goes as unique column in Table_A.

This is already set up in sql query, but I need to know whats the best practise and how to transform them into SSIS ? Should I use "Execute SQL Task" process flow 
or use data flow task involving oledb source and oledb destination ?

Answer (score 1):

Execute SQL Task is what you're going to want. The Execute SQL Task is designed to run an arbitrary query that may or may not return a result set. You've already done the hard work of getting your code working correctly so all you need to do is define a Connection Manager (likely an OLE DB) and paste in your code.

In this case, SSIS is going to be nothing more than a coordinator/execution framework for your existing SQL Process. And that's perfectly acceptable as someone who's written more than a few SSIS packages.

A Data Flow Task, I find, is more appropriate when you need to move the data from tables B, C, and D into a remote database or you need to perform transformation logic on them that isn't easily done in TSQL.

A Data Flow Task will not support creating the table at run-time. All SSIS tasks perform a validation check - either on package start or it can be delayed until the specific task begins. One of the checks a Data Flow Task is going to perform is "does the target table exist (and does the structure match my cached copy)?"